# Use of conjuncts in formal communication via email, letters etc

Tags: conjunctions, formality, letter-writing

How much should we use the conjuncts (words like *besides, however, nevertheless, otherwise, so, therefore, still, yet, though*) in formally communicating via email, verbally etc?

Any suggestions in what kind of communications we should lessen their use? I just want to know more about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is about "how much", "how many". The quantity by itself does not determine the degree of formality.

The words that you choose however do sound more formal or less formal. For example, compare the examples below:

1) less formal

> **But** the words that you use do sound more formal or less formal.

2) more formal

> The words that you use **however**
>   do sound more formal or less formal.

---

1) less formal (?)

> The cell phone is thin and light and **therefore** very convenient to carry around.

2) more formal (?)

> The cell phone is thin and light, **hence** very convenient to carry around.

---

1) less formal

> [...]**then** there is the interest to be paid.

2) more formal

> [...]**Additionally**, there is the the interest to be paid.